# how to completely remove ADB command from the windows10?

Tags: android, adb, react-native

I removed android studio, but adb command still works.
I need to know how to make this adb command unrecognized on windows10.

Answer (score 0):

Check environment **path** variable has path location of adb exe. OR if you have specified your own path variable for adb. Remove it then it should unrecognized adb.

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment path.
In the Windows menu search for "Environ" and you should see something like "Edit the environment variables of this account". It will open a window and in the bottom it will say "Enviromental variables". 
On the top part you will see your user variables. Click Path, Edit and check if "adb" might be in any of those folders.
If not, do the same for system variables (it will be the bottom section of the previous dialog). Once the Path reference has been erased (and ideally the file where it pointed) and a reboot, that should do the trick